# Django Celery tasks run twice

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

My project directory structure is as follows:

```
rss_reader  
 - reader  
    - __init__.py   
    - models.py  
    - views.py  
    - ...  
 - rss_reader  
    - __init__.py   
    - settings.py  
    - urls.py  
    - wsgi.py  
 - rss_contents  
    - __init__.py   
    - celery.py  
    - tasks.py  
    - config.py  
 - ...
```

tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from rss_contents.celery import app

@app.task
def processArticle():
    print "100"
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('rss_contents', include=['rss_contents.tasks'])
app.config_from_object('rss_contents.config')
```

config.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/5'
BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/6'
```

reader > __init__.py

```
from rss_contents import tasks
tasks.processArticle.delay()
```

---

#### My steps are as follows:

1. celery -A rss_contents worker -l info

The console displays:

```
[2017-01-11 10:34:33,829: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://127.0.0.1:6379/6  
[2017-01-11 10:34:33,855: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors  
[2017-01-11 10:34:34,861: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone  
[2017-01-11 10:34:34,892: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@DESKTOP-6KAT7MF ready.
```

2. Run server, Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

But the celery console shows that the task was run twice：

```
[2017-01-11 10:41:20,910: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: rss_contents.tasks.processArticle[aa355c77-4ee8-4208-9e8c-915b110c7bbd]  
[2017-01-11 10:41:20,911: WARNING/Worker-1] 100
[2017-01-11 10:41:20,917: INFO/MainProcess] Task rss_contents.tasks.processArticle[aa355c77-4ee8-4208-9e8c-915b110c7bbd] succeeded in 0.00600004196167s: None  

[2017-01-11 10:41:22,430: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: rss_contents.tasks.processArticle[d92a151c-f0f9-4e8f-921a-fff2c1eb64c6]  
[2017-01-11 10:41:22,431: WARNING/Worker-1] 100   
[2017-01-11 10:41:22,447: INFO/MainProcess] Task rss_contents.tasks.processArticle[d92a151c-f0f9-4e8f-921a-fff2c1eb64c6] succeeded in 0.0160000324249s: None
```

Why is it running twice? How can I do it once?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@enix nailed it on the head.  Because `reader` is an app, it is called once when django initializes the application registry.  But, since this invocation is made dynamically, the reader app may be getting initialized a second time because there is a global use of the reader package somewhere.  In any case, the easiest way to fix this is just to move your call to a class and call it from a singleton *in any python file*.

```
class AppInitializer(object):
    initialized = false

    @classmethod 
    def initialize(cls):
        if not cls.initialized:
            cls.initialized = True
            from rss_contents import tasks
            tasks.processArticle.delay()

AppInitializer.initialize()
```

If your appengine is multi-threaded, you’ll want to add a method lock around initialize.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have defined the task call in the `__init__.py` file.

I have started a test with your codes, and insert a pdb break inside the `__init__.py` like this

```
from celery_proj import tasks
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  # <-- make a break point here
print __file__
tasks.processArticle.delay()
```

and get the following interest findings:

when you run `python manage.py runserver`, the breakpoint is trigger once with the following stack trace:

```
(Pdb) where
  /Users/enix/Source/python/stackoverflow/sotest/manage.py(10)<module>()
-> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  /Users/enix/Source/python/bae/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py(353)execute_from_command_line()
-> utility.execute()
  /Users/enix/Source/python/bae/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py(316)execute()
-> autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  /Users/enix/Source/python/bae/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py(226)wrapper()
-> fn(*args, **kwargs)
  /Users/enix/Source/python/bae/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py(18)setup()
-> apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  /Users/enix/Source/python/bae/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py(85)populate()
-> app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  /Users/enix/Source/python/bae/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py(90)create()
-> module = import_module(entry)
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py(37)import_module()
-> __import__(name)
> /Users/enix/Source/python/stackoverflow/sotest/app/__init__.py(4)<module>()
-> print __file__
```

and when I type `c` to continue, the break point is trigger again with the same stack trace.

So your task is being called twice. But I am not quite sure why django will import the application package twice.

```
(bae)bogon:sotest enix$ python manage.py runserver
/Users/enix/Source/python/stackoverflow/sotest/app/__init__.py  # <-- print __file__
/Users/enix/Source/python/stackoverflow/sotest/app/__init__.pyc # <-- print __file__
Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 10, 2017 - 21:44:12
Django version 1.9.12, using settings 'sotest.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Maybe you should move your task call to other place and try again.

Comment: where to call task can be executed when the service starts running？

Comment: "But I am not quite sure why django will import the application package twice."
Django's `runserver` command starts two instances, because Django reloads the development server whenever you modify and/or save the source code. If you add the `--noreload` flag to `runserver`, then only one instance will spawn.